# Let $S$= Sup $M$. Prove there exists a sequence that converges to $S$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation, supremum-and-infimum

Let $S$=Sup $M.$ Prove there exists a sequence ($a_n$)$_{n=1}^{\infty}$ that converges to $S$ such that $a_n$ $\in$ $M$ for all natural numbers $n$.

Is there a way to prove this without assuming the sequence increases and without using the squeeze theorem?

So far, I have this:

By the definition of a supremum of a nonempty set, $M,$ we know that Sup $M$=$S$ is the least upper bound of $M.$ If we have a sequence $a_n$ $\in$ $M$ for all natural numbers $n,$ we can construct $a_n$ $\in S$ such that |$a_n - S$| < $\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$=$1\over n.$ Then -|$1\over n$|$\leq$|$a_n-S$|$\leq$|$1\over n$|.

Since |$a_n-S$| is bounded, we know that there exists a number, $x\in M$ such that $S - \epsilon \leq x < S$ for all $\epsilon$ >0.*

*This last sentence is from a previously proven theorem which states that: 
Suppose $M = (a,b)$, and Sup $M=S$. Then for every number $\epsilon$ > 0, there exists a number $x$ in $M$ such that $S - \epsilon \leq x < S.$

I'm not sure if I am on the right track, and was hoping for guidance in solving this proof without using the Squeeze theorem and without assuming the sequence increases.

Comment: We do not know that for $\epsilon >0$ there exists $x\in M$ with $S-\epsilon\leq x<S$. For example we could have $M=\{S\}$ or $M=\{S\}\cup \{S-n:n\in \mathbb N\} $. What we know is that for $\epsilon>0$ there exists $x\in M$ with $S-\epsilon <x\leq S.$.... You are on the right track. Just let $a_n\in (S-1/n,S]$ for each $n$ and you're done.

Comment: Does this prove the existence of the sequence as well?

Comment: If $\max S$ exists we can let $a_n=\max S$ for each $n.$ If $\sup S$ exists and  $\max S$ does not , then for each $n$ we can  let $a_n\in (-2^{-n}+\sup S,\sup S)$ for each n. Or we can do both cases in one sentence:  Let $a_n\in (2^{-n}+\sup S, \sup S].$ .... And $\lim_{n\to \infty }a_n=\sup S$  in all of these.... Note that this works because $\sup S$ is the LEAST upper bound for $S$. It won't work for any larger upper bound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement:

> Since |$a_n-S$| is bounded, we know that there exists a number, $x\in M$ such that $S - \epsilon \leq x < S$ for all $\epsilon$ >0.*

is stated incorrectly. In fact, there can be no such $x$ since it would satisfy $S \le x < S$.

Prior to that you essentially had the right answer. For each $n$ you can find $a_n \in M$ satisfying $S - \frac 1n < a_n \le S$, from which it follows $|a_n - S| < \frac 1n$ for all $n$.

Given $\epsilon > 0$ choose $N$ satisfying $\frac 1N < \epsilon$. Then $$n \ge N \implies |a_n - S| < \frac 1n \le \frac 1N < \epsilon.$$ This is  the definition of $a_n \to S$.

Comment: How do you get  |$a_n−S$|<$1\over n$ from the first part? Wouldn't you get the opposite result subtracting $S$ from each side? And do you mean n≥N⟹|$a_n−S$|<$1\over n$ ≤ $1\over N$ <ϵ ?